# How to make vassal from your own provinces?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I earned in war, as a Imperator in the Holy Roman Empire, Ansbach province with idea that I will let them free as my vassal. But after I earn it I don't see any option to make it happen.

This was possible in EU III so I hope they let to make this possible in next game iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It is in diplomacy tab on your own state tab.